# difference between using $and or $match in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

is there any difference or advantage between using $and for matching multiple values for a field and using $match with $in?

```
db.collectionOne.aggregate([
{$match:{name:{'$in':['Jack','Jill']},
        city:{'$in':['LA','NY']}
        }
      }])
```

or

```
db.collectionOne.aggregate([
{$match:{
  $and:[{name:{'$in':['Jack','Jill']},
        city:{'$in':['LA','NY']}
        }
  ]}
}])
```

or should $and only be used for numerical values to get better performance?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i think there is a typo in your example. It should be

```
db.collectionOne.aggregate([
{$match:{
  $and:[{name:{'$in':['Jack','Jill']}},
        {city:{'$in':['LA','NY']}
        }
  ]}
}])
```

**And both the snippets you use are the same as mention on this page** 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

> Note
>
> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and
>   operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions.

So use $and when you need to apply two condition on same key, as shown below.

```
db.collectionOne.aggregate([
{$match:{
  $and:[{name:{'$in':['Jack','Jill','Bill','Kill']}},
        {name:{'$nin':['Matt','Bill']}
        }
  ]}
}])
```

Above example is not good, but it explains the scenario

Comment: there isn't a typo, but the same query can be used both ways(mine and urs). But I do get your point that it isnt a good eg. Cant I just use `db.collectionOne.aggregate([
{$match:{name:{'$in':['Jack','Jill','Bill','Kill']},
               name:{'$nin':['Matt','Bill']}
               }
  }])` instead of using $and. What performance difference does these two have?

Comment: I said typo because $and is intended to use to implement multiple condition on a single field, as mentioned in my answer,

But the way you use is not correct

db.collectionOne.aggregate([
{$match:{
  $and:[{name:{'$in':['Jack','Jill','Bill','Kill']},
        name:{'$nin':['Matt','Bill']}
        }
  ]}
}])

Comment: I did go through the same page before asking, and the docs make more sense to use $and for boolean type AND operations. But I have seen many people use $and in place of $match even when there is no boolean type operation to perform.